# set dynamic variable name in jstl while using MAP

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, jstl, jstl-functions

I need to set the dynamic value for the `var` in `jstl`,
My code is

```
<c:forEach var="entry" items="${mapData}">
    <c:set var="row${entry.key}" value="${entry.value}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

and want the expected out put like this

`var = value`

`value = key`

`var` value has to be dynamic.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Still not clear what you desire and what's not working?

Comment: I want to set the dynamic variable name based on `map` key value.

Comment: So what is the problem with your current code? isn't it working?